# Swift project on GitHub travis-ci check always fail?

Tags: swift, github, travis-ci

I don't know how to edit my `.travis.yml`. Every time travis-ci check fail, I am almost crazy!

This is my travis-ci link: https://travis-ci.org/liman123/DebugMan

This is my `.travis.yml`, is there anything wrong? Thanks!

```
osx_image: xcode8.3
language: objective-c

script:
- set -o pipefail && xcodebuild test -enableCodeCoverage YES -workspace 
DebugMan.xcworkspace -scheme DebugMan -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 
'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest' ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO | 
xcpretty
- pod lib lint
```

Comment: I used cocoapods in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
language: objective-c
script: 
  - xctool -project example.xcodeproj -scheme exampleTests build test -sdk 
iphonesimulator GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=YES 
GCC_GENERATE_TEST_COVERAGE_FILES=YES
after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

Comment: It does not work yet. I used cocoapods in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your first script command in double quotes:

`"set pipefail ... | xcpretty"`